# In windows envs, Cupy get error in multithread.pool if GPU already used, even if I have used multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error, cupy

I use the chainer framework to train my CNN. In order to speed up, I use the cupy and multiprocess package. However, even if I have added the multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn') statement, I still meet the error like this:

CUDARuntimeError.**init**

TypeError: an integer is required

My envs is:

```
win10

py3.7

cuda9.2
```

Before I asked this question, I have refered this link: [Cupy get error in multithread.pool if GPU already used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54808148/cupy-get-error-in-multithread-pool-if-gpu-already-used) . The total program code is too long, so I show part of my program( the function which raises the error) as follows:

```
class CNNEvaluation(object):

    def __init__(self, gpu_num, epoch_num=50, batchsize=256,dataset='cifar10', valid_data_ratio=0.1, verbose=True):

        self.gpu_num = gpu_num
        self.epoch_num = epoch_num
        self.batchsize = batchsize
        self.dataset = dataset
        self.valid_data_ratio = valid_data_ratio
        self.verbose = verbose

    def __call__(self, net_lists):
        ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')
        evaluations = np.zeros(len(net_lists))

        for i in np.arange(0, len(net_lists), self.gpu_num):
            process_num = np.min((i + self.gpu_num, len(net_lists))) - i
            pool = ctx.Pool(process_num)
            arg_data = [(cnn_eval, net_lists[i+j], j, self.epoch_num, self.batchsize, self.dataset,
                         self.valid_data_ratio, self.verbose) for j in range(process_num)]
            evaluations[i:i+process_num] = pool.map(arg_wrapper_mp, arg_data)
            pool.terminate()

        return evaluations
```

The output is like the following:

```
Exception in thread Thread-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\AppInstall\Anaconda3\envs\py3_7\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
File "D:\AppInstall\Anaconda3\envs\py3_7\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

  File "D:\AppInstall\Anaconda3\envs\py3_7\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 470, in _handle_results

    task = get()

  File "D:\AppInstall\Anaconda3\envs\py3_7\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 251, in recv

    return _ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())

  File "cupy\cuda\runtime.pyx", line 134, in 

cupy.cuda.runtime.CUDARuntimeError.__init__
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Then the code freezes and doesn't exit. I can't understand why I have added the multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn') statement, I still have the error message. Is it because I run the program in the windows envs instead of linux?

Answer (score 0):

This is because CuPy exceptions cannot be pickled, i.e. exceptions raised in child processes cannot be propagated to its parent process. This issue is going to be fixed in https://github.com/cupy/cupy/pull/2318.